# Ajax call using Django REST API python?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to pass multiple search fields to my Django API from my Ajax request but for some reason, its not filtering the results. I am still getting everything as if my search queries are not being passed to the Django API. What could i be doing wrong ?

**api.py**

```
from . import models
from . import serializers
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions, filters




class Useradviewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """ViewSet for the patientVisit class"""

    queryset = models.Userad.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.useradserializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('user_id','category','country')
```

**ajax request**

```
$.ajax({
       url: "/plentyofcats/api/v1/useradapi/",
            type: "get",
            data: {
                'category': 'msw',
                'country':'congo',

            },

            success: function (json) {
                console.log(json)
             }
});
```

Comment: Looks like everything is true, except that "GET" in lowercase